# IntelliTrace and ADO.NET parameter values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, entity-framework, intellitrace

I'm trying to debug Entity Framework, and I can see the DB calls, but parameter values are not shown. I tried a bunch of options, but was not able to see any of the parameters. Is it possible? If not, it would be a total let down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I know IntelliTrace doesn't show parameters for queries. It shows only command text. You need some external profiler to see queries with parameters. You can use SQL Profiler directly or try tools like:

- [EF Tracing Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32)
- [Huagati Query Profiler](http://www.huagati.com/L2SProfiler/)
- [EFProf](http://efprof.com/)
- [ORM Profiler](http://www.ormprofiler.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)
- In case of ASP.NET MVC you can also use [MVC mini profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/)

More about profiling options can be also found in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx).

Comment: And not forgetting you can profile at the DB level too. ie) SqlProfiler for MSSQL.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. MVC mini profiler might be the winner for me

Answer (score -1):

If you have your IntelliTrace settings configured to collect call information - Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> Events and Call Information then IntelliTrace will collect the values of parameters passed into methods in your code.

If the values that you are interested in are passed as method parameters at some point you should be able to step back through your code to inspect those values.  Keep the locals window open and you can see the historical values that IntelliTrace collects as you navigate backward.

Comment: The question is about parameters in SQL queries, not method parameters. SQL parameter values are not collected by IntelliTrace even if you turn on Call Information